# Required email headers

Tags: php, email

What headers are required in emails for Hotmail, Gmail and Yahoo?

Comment: ... to ... what?  Not be marked as spam?

Comment: @Shawn, yes i would like to know all necessary headers.

Comment: See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322

Answer (score 2):

While Gmail ostensibly suffers from the same problem of any well-designed interface -- that it hides too much information from advanced users in the interest of offering the best possible experience to novices -- the good news is that it's very easy to dig into a given email message and learn more about its headers. Even better, you can easily add the message sender to your contacts list, forward or print the message, and much more, all with one click.

The secret is the tiny little "More options" link that appears adjacent to the time and date that the message was sent on the header line.

Let me show you what I mean, okay?

Turns out that I'm going back and forth with Lexar support about a failing JumpDrive Secure USB keychain drive, and they finally approved my returning the unit for a replacement.
That's where all the options are hiding in Gmail. Notice that you can reply to the sender, reply to everyone on the recipient list, forward, print, add sender to contacts list, trash this message, report phishing and... the last option... what you asked for: "Show original". Click on that link and you'll be shown the exact header of the message, including the Gmail-added header "X-Gmail-Received".

I think that should address your issue. The moral of this little story? Poke around in Gmail and you'll be pleased and surprised at the many capabilities are hidden just one or two mouse clicks away.

Comment: +1, very good and thorough answer. Keep it up :)

Comment: Cool, but doesn't really answer the question "what headers are *required*".